# jQuery highcharts multiline

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Eu tenho um aplicativo MVC e gostaria de esclarecer algumas dúvidas de como implementar um gráfico com os dados do banco de dados. Eu estou usando jQuery para obter os valores do banco de dados, mas não entendia como pegar esses valores e gerar um gráfico usando Highcharts, eu leio muito na internet, mas não estava claro como obter e colocar os valores no eixo x e do eixo y.

Para os valores de X e Y eixos, estou usando o seguinte:

```asp
Dictionary <decimal, decimal> dataResult = new Dictionary <decimal, decimal> ();
```

Para fazer a consulta no banco de dados e montar a seguinte:

```asp
foreach (var item in query) 
{
     dataResult.Add (Convert.ToDecimal (item.valorinicial), Convert.ToDecimal (item.preco)); 

}
```

Para passar o valor:

```
return Json (dataResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Para gerar o Gráfico, mudei para:

```
var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: "container",
                },
                series: [{}]
            };



        $.getJSON("/GraficosLev/GetDadosByGraf", { ...parametros passados.... },
            function (data) {
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        ignoreHiddenSeries: false
                    },

                    xAxis: {
                    },


                    series: data
                });
        });
```

Para a busca dos dados:

```
Dictionary<decimal, decimal> dataResult = new Dictionary<decimal, decimal>();

        public object GetValuesByGraf(int? idRod, int? idLev, string codLev, string kmIni, string kmFim)
        {
            string tpLev = (from l in db.TIPO_LEVA where l.id == idLev select l.tipo_levantamento).FirstOrDefault();
            //Conta o numero de datas Selecionadas
            string[] codLevant = codLev.Split(',');

            foreach (string i in codLevant)
            {
                //pega os valores do id do codigo de levantmanto para pegar os levantamentos
                int idCodLev = (from l in db.LEV1
                               where l.cod_levantamento == i
                               select l.id).FirstOrDefault();

                if (tpLev =="I")
                {
                    var query = (from iri in db.IRR10
                                      where iri.cod_levantamento_id == idCodLev
                                      select iri);

                    foreach (var item in query)
                    {
                        dataResult.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(item.inicial), Convert.ToDecimal(item.iri));

                    }
                }
            }



            return dataResult;
        }
```

Comment: Poderia ser mais específica? Você quer entender como usar o hightcharts ou quer corrigir algo específico no seu código?

Comment: Cara, acho que seria muito mais fácil você olhar o demo e fazer igual: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/

Comment: Gostaria de saber como usar o hightcharts para gerar o grafico, mas parece que estou chamando o grafico antes da função pegar os dados.

Comment: não, ele apenas esta montando as opções do grafico antes da chamada e após ela e adiciona as series e assim sim chama o grafico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observando as respostas e comentários observei que na configuração o `renderTo` está para o `container`. Este realmente é o `id` do elemento que deve receber o *chart*?

Você também pode definir seu *chart* usando [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):

```
$('#container').highcharts(options);
```

Usar [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) (`$('#container')`) ou passar direto no [json](/questions/tagged/json) (`renderTo: 'container'`) fazem o mesmo efeito, portanto utilize apenas uma das opções e confira se o `id` do elemento confere com o que está no `renderTo`.

Seu código poderia ficar assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Submit").click(function (evt) {
     //
     //Algumas Variaveis
     //

        jQuery.get("/ChartLev/GetByGraf", { ...passo os parametros....} }, function (values) {
            $.each(values, function (key, val) {
                data.push({
                    name: val.key,
                    data: val.Value
                })
            });
        });
        var options = {
            chart: {
                backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                borderColor: '#a2a2a1',
                borderWidth: 0,
                borderRadius: 0,
                type: 'area',
                plotBackgroundColor: '#fffdf6'
            },
            colors: ['#3399FF'],
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Graf'
            },
            tooltip: {
                borderRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 0,
                shadow: false,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '7pt',
                    color: '#000000'
                },
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value
                }
            },
            xAxis: {

                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    x: 0,
                    y: 40,
                    style: {
                        color: '#333333'
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: '#333333',
                minPadding: 0,
                maxPadding: 0,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                tickInterval: 2,
                tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
            },
            yAxis: {
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value},
                    style: {
                        color: '#333333'
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: '#333333',
                min: 0,
                minPadding: 0,
                maxPadding: 0,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            series: data
        };
        $('#container').highcharts(options);
    });
});
```

E no seu html:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Teria algum exemplo para mostrar ?

Comment: vou editar e colocar como poderia ficar seu código

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda, não estou conseguindo gerar esse grafico...

Comment: Está dando algum erro? caso sim poderia colar aqui pra nós o erro? Caso não poderia colar aqui o retorno que o seu ajax está gerando?

Comment: Não esta gerando erro, apenas não aparece a linha do gráfico.Então faço a consulta normal no banco de dados e ele me retorna os valores de duas colunas. 
"14,2,5"
"14.5,5"
e assim por diante.

Comment: tem como colar o [tag:json] exato que teu ajax gera? Da uma olhada no request do browser e cola a resposta o [tag:ajax] pra galera poder ver.

Comment: Vou acrescentar na pergunta.

Comment: acabei de editar o meu `series`  olha se modifica o que tu tem. Teu series tem que ser exatamente assim `[{
 name: 'Tokyo',
 data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
}, {
 name: 'New York',
 data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
}, {
 name: 'Berlin',
 data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
}, {
 name: 'London',
 data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
}]`

Comment: Acabei de colocar o código. Mas ele acho que não gera desta forma.

Comment: Entendi o problema, mas como que faço para formatar desta forma após pegar os dados no banco de dados ?
Teria que ser desta forma [{name: 'dados1', data:[[1,2.5],[2,2.6]]}]

Comment: Da uma olhada [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/sB3yw/) você precisa retornar os seu dados nesse formato

Comment: @rysahara isso é o [tag:json] [aqui](http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/) ou [aqui](http://www.webdevbros.net/2007/04/26/generate-json-from-asp-datatypes/) para pegar classes em [tag:asp.net] para trabalhar com [tag:json] se quiser outras referências olhe em http://www.json.org/

Comment: Muito Obrigado pelos links, vou estuda-los para ver como implementar da forma correta.

Comment: Por nada se puder dar um upvote na resposta e se depois de estudar ela tiver resolvido seu problema, marca como resolvido, vou agradecer muuuito.
:D

Comment: Pode deixar.....

Answer (score 1):

não seria "data" ao inves de "y"

```
 name: val.key,
 data: val.Value
```

Comment: Realmente isso vai fazer uma diferença bem grande

Comment: Não gerou o gráfico mesmo com essa mudança.

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso (valor inicial e preço), o gráfico poderia ser montado usando [este exemplo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic).

Usando [este pacote NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNet.Highcharts/).

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult BasicBar()
{
    Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
        .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Bar })
        .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Historic World Population by Region" })
        .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle { Text = "Source: Wikipedia.org" })
        .SetXAxis(new XAxis
            {
                Categories = new[] { "Africa", "America", "Asia", "Europe", "Oceania" },
                Title = new XAxisTitle { Text = string.Empty }
            })
        .SetYAxis(new YAxis
        {
                Min = 0,
                Title = new YAxisTitle
                {
                    Text = "Population (millions)",
                    Align = AxisTitleAligns.High
                }
        })
        .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return ''+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' millions'; }" })
        .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
        {
            Bar = new PlotOptionsBar
            {
                DataLabels = new PlotOptionsBarDataLabels { Enabled = true }
            }
        })
        .SetLegend(new Legend
        {
            Layout = Layouts.Vertical,
            Align = HorizontalAligns.Right,
            VerticalAlign = VerticalAligns.Top,
            X = -100,
            Y = 100,
            Floating = true,
            BorderWidth = 1,
            BackgroundColor = new BackColorOrGradient(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF")),
            Shadow = true
        })
        .SetCredits(new Credits { Enabled = false })
        .SetSeries(new[]
        {
            new Series { Name = "Year 1800", Data = new Data(new object[] { 107, 31, 635, 203, 2 }) },
            new Series { Name = "Year 1900", Data = new Data(new object[] { 133, 156, 947, 408, 6 }) },
            new Series { Name = "Year 2008", Data = new Data(new object[] { 973, 914, 4054, 732, 34 }) }
        });

        return View(chart);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Meu gráfico";
}

<h2>Meu gráfico</h2>

@(Model)
```

Tem mais exemplos [neste arquivo](https://github.com/fairmat/DotNet.Highcharts/tree/master/DotNet.Highcharts/DotNet.Highcharts.Samples).

Tem mais um pacote no NuGet, o [Highcharts.net](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Highcharts.Net/) , mas este não achei exemplos de uso, embora seja feito por um brasileiro e tenha comentários positivos na página do projeto: http://highcharts.codeplex.com/. Acho que seria o caso de testar caso a caso.

Comment: Mas eu estou passando os valores via jquery. Eu li este exemplo, mas estou tendo problemas em passar os valores para a série, para gerar o grafico.